# How to change the placeholder value for a dynamically fetched text?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am storing my query in database like below

[image]

While fetching I need to replace the filterId by user inputs.

I tried the below

```
let filterId = req.body.ids;  // filterId is the placeholder in database
fetchQuery(type, function((responseQuery){
         console.log(responseQuery) // this still printing the placeholder not the user input
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is evaluated upon compilation, you should `eval()` to accomplish this.
It would be kind of fun to try.

```js
var x = 12; 
var str = 'hello ${x}';

var combined = ( eval ("`" + str + "`") )

console.log(combined)
```