# Is there a way to create a var by concat a string with a int in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out what likely is simple.  I have a for loop of unknown length.  I'd like to do something like the following where nearby_ports_x gets x from the loop.  So I might have nearby_ports_0 ... nearby_ports_x  The nearby_port_x ... would the be use to post

```
for (x = 0; x < document.getElementsByClassName("nearby_ports").length; x++) {
    nearby_ports_x = document.getElementsByClassName("nearby_ports")[x].href;
}
```

Comment: btw use `let` instead of `int`, since `int` isn't a thing in javascript

Comment: What is `nearby_ports_x ` ? do you want everything to += it? (concat)

Comment: @ITgoldman I think they want `nearby_ports_0`, `nearby_ports_1`, ..., `nearby_ports_534`, etc.

Comment: Calling Dr. Eval

Comment: @ITgoldman don't suggest `eval`. It's a terrible practice.

Comment: OP, there is (almost always) no reason to make variables the way you're wanting to. Create an array/object instead that you would access as `nearby_ports[0]`, `nearby_ports[1]`, etc.

Comment: @VLAZ it is bad practice if you run it on user input. Sometimes there's no other option. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72696657/how-to-change-the-placeholder-value-for-a-dynamically-fetched-text/72696895#72696895

Comment: @ITgoldman it's almost never the only option. Unless you've taken several wrong steps way before you got to that point. It's a terrible practice because it has some unintuitive semantics to it. Moreover, you have to write code that produces other code. And there are a bunch of potential pitfalls to that practice as well. And above all, you have to do all of that *instead of* writing proper code that correctly lays own instructions to achieve an effect. Which you can further enhance in various programmatic ways. `eval` doesn't even allow syntax highlighting - the first protection against bugs.

Comment: @ IT goldman  I have a api that currently would accept in the form nearby_ports_0 ... nearby_ports_10

Comment: @AlwaysResearching I know I offered to use `eval` see duplicate answer. @VLAZ yes but sometimes it's the only option if some1 else took the wrong steps for you. Besides, you have to admit it's most awesome function and the most dreaded one.

Comment: @Samathingamajig yes although I am trying to post to an api which requires

Comment: @AlwaysResearching please include more details. Posting to an API does not send the name of your variables (it does a similar thing though if you create an object and serialize it to json)